# Is it possible to get value right after api call?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Suppose I have a react component as,

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function BookFunction() {

    const [bookData, setBookData] = useState([]);
    const [randomValue, setRandomValue] = useState([])

        function fetchInfo() {
            axios.post(`/api/book/bookDetails`).then((data) => {
                setBookData(data.data)
                }).catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                })
                console.log(bookData) => Gives empty array
                const bookReadingTime = bookData.filter(based on somethings)
                setRandomValue(bookReadingTime)
        }
     
     return(
         <div><button onClick={fetchInfo}/> </div>
         {randomValue === undefined ? <p>{randomValue} </p> :null}
     )

}
```

Is there any way when I call this function and print the value it gives me value as I need set it to random value and pass to paragraph to be displayed? Please let me know if anyone needs any further information.

Comment: If you want the code to execute after the request completes it needs to be inside the `then` with the call to `setBookData` otherwise it will run before any data is requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly update the randomValue state in .then of Promise.

```
export default function BookFunction() {

    const [bookData, setBookData] = useState([]);
    const [randomValue, setRandomValue] = useState([])

        function fetchInfo() {
            axios.post(`/api/book/bookDetails`).then((data) => {
                setBookData(data.data);
                setRandomValue(data.data);
                }).catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                })
                
        }
     
     return(
         <div><button onClick={fetchInfo}/> </div>
         {randomValue === undefined ? <p>{randomValue} </p> :null}
     )

}
```

or if you application updates bookData at multiple places, you can make use of `useEffect`

```
export default function BookFunction() {

    const [bookData, setBookData] = useState([]);
    const [randomValue, setRandomValue] = useState([])

        function fetchInfo() {
            axios.post(`/api/book/bookDetails`).then((data) => {
                setBookData(data.data);
                
                }).catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                })
                
        }
     useEffect(() => {
      if(bookData) {
        setRandomValue(bookData);
      }
    }, [bookData]);
     return(
         <div><button onClick={fetchInfo}/> </div>
         {randomValue === undefined ? <p>{randomValue} </p> :null}
     )

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be,

useEffect(() => {
       fetchInfo();
        setRandomValue(bookData);
    }, [bookData]);

Comment: I have edited the question, as it was not clear I guess. I don't want to use useEffect. onclick of button function should be called and from api fetch value, set in bookDetails perform some operation and set into randomValue. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: @SivaPradhan, useEffect is not used as you have mentioned but as I used in the code. What it effectively does is that after setting bookData you can do any operation you want with the book data and update randomValue state. Also you can go by the first solution where you update randomValue state with the data obtained from api rather than relying on bookData state

Comment: are you able to print the value of book data inside useEffect(),

eg.: useEffect(() => {
      if(bookData) {
        console.log('bookData',bookData')
      }
    }, [bookData]);

As it is giving me blank. No value inside book data

Comment: Are you checking the logs, after you have clicked on the button to fetchInfo? because if your data is correctly fetched and updated in bookData state, it should work

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Its working fine now. There was some logical error as I was trying with different code So while implementation over there I did some mistake. But any how, thanks a lot . :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can access the data inside then block.

```
function fetchInfo() {
        axios.post(`/api/book/bookDetails`).then((data) => {
            setBookData(data.data)
            setRandomValue(data.data)
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            })      
    }
```

you are updating `bookData` varaible with `data.data` value. The same `bookData` you want to update in `randomvalue`. You can try above syntax.

Comment: I have edited the question please have a look.

Comment: That filtering part also you can include inside the then block.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `useEffect` first of all, your `fetchInfo` should be inside it.
Also, you don't need both state, there are the same in your example

```
useEffect(() => {
  function fetchInfo() {
    axios.post(`/api/book/bookDetails`).then((data) => {
      setBookData(data.data);
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    })
  }
})
```

There was another problem here, you should just return a single tag

```
return(
    <div>
        <button onClick={fetchInfo}>Fetch</button>
        {randomValue === undefined ? <p>{randomValue} </p> :null}
    </div>
)
```